# Error para subir archivos php-jquery-ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Html:

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <form id="formulario1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input id="archivo1" type="file" name="name_archivo">
        <label id="label1" for="archivo1">Elige un archivo</label>
        <div id="boton_archivo">Sube archivo</div>

    </form>

</div>
```

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#boton_archivo').on('click', function() { // Subida de archivos

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('archivo',document.getElementById('archivo1').files[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'subida.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        success: function(respuesta){
            alert(respuesta);
        }
    });

});

$('#archivo1').on('change', function(event) {

    var nombre = document.getElementById('archivo1');
    var variable = nombre.files[0].name;
    document.getElementById('label1').innerHTML = variable;

}); });
```

Php:

```
<?php
$auxiliar = "";
$path_archivo = "";
$ext_archivo = "";
$error = 0;

if(isset($_FILES['name_archivo']['name'])){

    $carpeta = "uploads/";
    $path_archivo = $carpeta.$_FILES['name_archivo']['name']; // uploads/domi.jpg
    $ext_archivo = pathinfo($path_archivo,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if (file_exists($path_archivo)) {
        $auxiliar = "Este nombre de archivo ya existe en el servidor.";
        $error = 1;
    }
    else{
        if ($_FILES['name_archivo']['size'] > 500000) {
            $auxiliar = "El peso del archivo sobrepasa lo establecido (500KB).";
            $error = 1;
        }
        else{
            if ($ext_archivo != "pdf") {
                $auxiliar = "Solo se aceptan archivos PDF.";
                $error = 1;
            }
        }

    }

    if ($error == 1) {
        echo "Ha habido un error: ".$auxiliar;
    }
    else{
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['name_archivo']['tmp_name'], $path_archivo)) {
            echo "El archivo ".$_FILES['name_archivo']['name']." se ha subido correctamente.";
        }
    }

}
else{
    echo "Vacio...";
}?>
```

El `label` lo uso para poder darle estilo al `input` file.
El problema es que me sigue apareciendo el mensaje "Vacio...", no entiendo el porque no esta llegando al php el archivo.

Comment: Agrega esto a la llamada Ajax: `contentType: false,` lo puedes poner antes de `processData: false,`

Comment: Ya, no hubo cambios :/

Answer (score 0):

Si le sirve a alguien, mi error estaba en esta linea del archivo php:

```
if(isset($_FILES['name_archivo']['name'])){
```

Debia cambiarla por

```
if(isset($_FILES['archivo']['name'])){
```

Ergo, todas las otras lineas donde estuviera `$_FILES['name_archivo']` tambien habria que cambiarlas.